# Minimum Between 3 Attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to prepare a flow that calculates in how many installments we can divide a purchase.

There are 3 conflicting business rules that give different answers. Our rule is to return the lesser value.

However how can I instruct a UpdateAttribute processor to return the minimum between the 3 attributes that contain the number returned by the business rules?

Comment: Show your research and an attempt at a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two UpdateAttribute processors in a row, lets say you have three attributes a, b, and c.

The first UpdateAttribute has something like:

result = ${a:lt(b):ifElse(a, b)}

Now result is the lesser of a and b.

Second UpdateAttribute:

result = ${result:lt(c):ifElse(result, c)}

Now result is the lesser of the previous result and c.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ExecuteGroovyScript processor with code like:

```
def ff=session.get()
if( !ff )return
ff.result = [ ff.a, ff.b, ff.c ].collect{ it as BigDecimal }.max()
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```